# Pixel lines using Shape builder tool Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, pixel

I'm doing a logo design and these messy lines appears after using shape builder tool in Illustrator. See the image. It's the faded lines on the intersections between the P and the A. I have tried several things but cannot get rid of them. And they mess up the clean look.

[image: The logo where the pixel lines are]

Anyone able to help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any faded lines on my screen between the P and the A. What I do notice is that the kerning of the letters "bureauet" are quite irregular.

Answer (score 1):

Those are hairlines, and they most probably will not show in any export you do -- it's darn hard to see them on the screenshot you posted. If you really want to be rid of them, you could try and edit the shapes that make the 'P' by hand. Add some anchor points, have to different shapes overlap (instead of border), and unite them using the pathfinder palette or shape builder.

Answer (score 1):

If you look the artwork over carefully, you'll see that the Shape Builder tool has created a set of adjacent paths for each of the letters. The hairlines show up where the paths abut, because of Ai's anti-aliasing.

To make them go away, use the Direct Selection (white arrow) tool with the Shift key to select the main P shape and the small sections that overlap the A, then merge them using the Pathfinder tool so that you have one compound path instead of a compound path and two additional paths.